# Point-biserial correlation with unequal groups in dichotomous variable

Tags: correlation, categorical-data

The dichotomous variable I want to use for a point-biserial correlation has very unequal n's ($n_1=140$, $n_2=6$). Would this be breaking any rules? What would this mean for my results? Would it just limit the statistical power?

Comment: 1) No, it doesn't break formal assumptions for point-biserial _r_. 2) Yes it does limit statistical power.

Answer (score 1):

I would first look at a scatterplot of the variables to see if they are linear before running an analysis. In addition, see Kraemer's 1980 paper,[Robustness of the Distribution Theory of the Product Moment Correlation Coefficient](http://jstor.org/stable/info/1164676), in which it is noted,

> Robustness of normal test theory for correlation coefficients is at
>   least asymptotically ensured for bivariate distributions satisfying a
>   linearity and a homoscedasticity condition for the null theory and a
>   further kurtosis condition for the nonnull theory. If any one of these
>   conditions fail, it may be demonstrated that robustness may fail as
>   well. (Abstract)

Comment: One variable is continuous. The dichotomous variable has the unequal group sizes.